# Difference between an iOS Enterprise app and iOS retail app

Tags: ios, app-store, enterprise

I used to work on an Enterprise iOS product which our company used to sell to big enterprise companies for their employee to use.

The app was made available via the AppStore and the enterprise users were provided company specific profiles (containing app config files) to enable the respective feature that they were entitled to and use the iOS software. This app is only meant for enterprise customers and their employees only.

I would want to know/understand what is the difference between Enterprise iOS app and a normal retail app (an individual publishing an iOS app in store for retail consumers to buy and use) as I was asked this question in one of the interviews.

One thing I know is the for Enterprise apps, you will have tons of paper work, T&C and NDA's to be signed between the Enterprise customer's IT and the app providing organization.

Apart from this is are there any differences? I mean any differences with respect to the way app is submitted to the store? Or any additional security requirements for an app as it is an enterprise app? Is there something that differentiates and enterprise app from an normal app?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Your terminology is confusing, as Enterprise apps cannot be submitted or downloaded from Apple's iOS App store.  Perhaps you have incorrectly described a B2B app?

Answer (score 1):

Your app cannot have been developed using an Apple enterprise account and Enterprise distribution profiles because Enterprise apps cannot be placed in the app store.

There is no difference in terms of development of an Enterprise app versus a non enterprise app, there's nothing additional to do (there's a little extra to do to distribute it, see last paragraph).

The only differences are you have to have an Apple Enterprise developer account and its gets signed with a different set of certificates and profiles.

As an Enterprise app does not go onto the App store is is not subject to Apple app store review and therefore you can implement more functionality that you could with a regular app (for example, you could use background modes, use private apis etc.).

There is additional work required to distribute the app, you typically might host it on a web site and make it available for download by the Enterprise users, you have to set up a few bits and pieces and create a manifest file to enable all that.